What is the holiest "thing" ever?
Obviously besides for God Himself, and also perhaps the greatest tzadiqim (righteous people) in history, what else is considered the holiest "thing" ever? (Is it the two luhoth (tablets)? If yes, please offer either a source or an explanation why.)
Please excuse the term "thing" in this question, I simply can't think of a better word. If you can please share!
The practical application to this question would be to give priority to save said "thing" from desecration.

What definition of "thing" are you working with that includes God and people and tablets?

@shmosel What's a better word? Or are you trying to harass me?

What is your definition of "holier than"? Are you asking if you would save that thing from fire? Stand up first for it? Can an object to a person? If we don't understand the question, it will be very hard to answer

@mbloch We can start with your example case of saving that thing from fire

It's just not very clear what you're asking. What's holier, the Torah or a Sefer Torah? Is that even a sensible question?

Start by defining holy. Which by the way means separate or unique.

Hashem is not a thing - yesh meayin. Neither are tzaddikim

The Mishnah teaches that there are ten degrees of holiness in Judaism.  [Kelim 1:5-9] Many examples are given.  Broadly speaking:
-The Land of Israel is holier than all other lands.
-Jerusalem is holier than other cities in the Land.
-Temple Mount is holier than other parts of Jerusalem.
-The Holy of Holies is holier than other parts of the Temple.
-And the holiest place in the Holy of Holies is the point centered above the Ark, between the Keruvim, the cherubs, from which the Voice of God emanates.

Is that mishnah referring to all "things" or only to areas of land?

Only locations, in this Mishna. Elsewhere (ref?) the relative holiness of the sacrifices is given.
